# NSPredicate ANY only returning records which match the keyword of their first element in list of strings

Tags: swift, nspredicate, cloudkit

I have a CKRecordType filled with recipes which include a list of strings for ingredients. How do I query a list of recipes which include two ingredients anywhere in the list of ingredients?

```
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY ingredients == %@","egg")
```

Here is the list that the above query returns, notice that the recipes that are returned are only the ones where the first ingredient is "egg".

```
Name: 1 minute breakfast sandwich
Recipe_id: 533190
Ingredients:
    0: egg
    1:  milk
    2:  salt
    3:  pepper
    4:  cooking spray
    5:  english muffin
    6:  cheese
    7:  bacon
    8:  tomatoes
    9:  basil
    10:  avocado
    11:  red pepper flakes"
Name: caesar dressing
Recipe_id: 528367
Ingredients:
    0: egg
    1:  egg yolk
    2:  white wine vinegar
    3:  lemon
    4:  juice of
    5:  salt
    6:  fresh ground black pepper
    7:  mustard powder
    8:  cayenne
    9:  white pepper
    10:  parmigiano-reggiano cheese
    11:  extra virgin olive oil
    12:  thai fish sauce
    13:  garlic cloves"
Name: cajun hush puppies
Recipe_id: 503126
Ingredients:
    0: egg
    1:  buttermilk
    2:  green onion
    3:  water
    4:  cornmeal
    5:  flour
    6:  brown sugar
    7:  baking powder
    8:  baking soda
    9:  salt
    10:  ground red pepper
    11:  vegetable oil"
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, it's the way I'm parsing the csv. Notice that the first ingredient is the only one starting with an empty space.

So, I run this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY ingredients == %@"," egg")
```

as opposed to this:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY ingredients == %@","egg")
```

I get results where "egg" is in the middle of the ingredients list, like this:

```
Name: carrot apple zucchini bread
Recipe_id: 537241
Ingredients:
    0: unsalted butter
    1:  granulated sugar
    2:  eggs
    3:  fresh orange juice
    4:  vanilla extract
    5:  all-purpose flour
    6:  salt
    7:  baking powder
    8:  baking soda
    9:  cinnamon
    10:  ground cloves
    11:  ground nutmeg
    12:  carrots
    13:  zucchini
    14:  apple
    15:  pecans
    16:  cream cheese
    17:  butter
    18:  powdered sugar
    19:  orange juice
    20:  water"
Name: amish triple butter biscuits
Recipe_id: 536384
Ingredients:
    0: flour
    1:  salt
    2:  cream of tartar
    3:  sugar
    4:  baking powder
    5:  butter
    6:  egg
    7:  milk"
Name: blueberry cheesecake crumb cake
Recipe_id: 535644
Ingredients:
    0: flour
    1:  baking powder
    2:  salt
    3:  butter
    4:  lemon
    5:  light brown sugar
    6:  sugar
    7:  eggs
    8:  vanilla
    9:  mascarpone
    10:  cream cheese
    11:  caster sugar
    12:  cornstarch
    13:  blueberries
    14:  powdered sugar
    15:  milk"
```